# Javascript + Razor for(var in list ) of for (var ; var < list , var++)?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

This is my code:

```
  for (var f = 0; f < @Model.Article.ListImage.Count(); f++)
  {
  let mockFile = { name: "Imagen" + i, size: 12345, type: 'image/*' };

  this.displayExistingFile(mockFile, "http://localhost:49407/file/Image/" + ??????, function () {
  }, 'crossOrigin', '');
  this.options.resize(mockFile)
  this.emit('complete', mockFile);
  let fileCountOnServer = 1;
  this.options.maxFiles = this.options.maxFiles - fileCountOnServer;

  i++;
  }
```

@Model.Article.ListImage is a list of ints.
So i want to create a mockfile for every number of the list.

When i need to concat the url with de number, **how should i take or handle the value**???

Also, there is posible to do in javascript something like...

for (var f in @Model.Article.ListImage) ??

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, but im not really sure if this is the correct way to do it:

```
 var Array = [];

            @foreach(var data in @Model.Article.ListImage)
            {
                @:Array.push("@data");
            }
            for (var f = 0; f < Array.length; f++)
            {

            let mockFile = { name: "Imagen" + i, size: 12345, type: 'image/*' };

            this.displayExistingFile(mockFile, "http://localhost:49407/file/Image/" + Array[f], function () {
            }, 'crossOrigin', '');
            this.options.resize(mockFile)
            this.emit('complete', mockFile);
            let fileCountOnServer = 1;
            this.options.maxFiles = this.options.maxFiles - fileCountOnServer;

            i++;

            }
```